# How to have multiple label one above and one below the edges in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I've the following output currently I want to place a label below the edge between p and z in the figure.Is it possible to do in graphviz I've tried using xlabels but it doesn't work.

[image: Diagram of a procedure]

Current Code:

```
digraph GPG{
node [shape=box]; 
subgraph cluster0{
    node[shape=circle];
    0[label=0,style=invis];

}
subgraph cluster1{
    node[shape=circle];
    1[label=1,style=invis];
    p->z [label="2 | 1",minlen=1];
    {
        rank = same;
        p;z;
    }
}

subgraph cluster2{
    node[shape=circle];
    2[label=2,style=invis];
}
0->1
1->2
```

}

I want a label below edge p->z as well above the edge.Is it possible in graphviz?

Comment: That should be possible but without your code for the output you have now, difficult and too much effort. If you post what you have, there shall be answers!

Comment: Are you wanting to place "2|1" below the edge, or do you want a second label below the edge?  Source would be helpful.

Comment: I want a second label below the edge

Answer (score 0):

Kind of ugly, but:

```
digraph overunder{
  splines=false
    { rank=same
    a -> b [label="&nbsp;over&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"  ] 
    a -> b [label="under" penwidth=0.0 dir=none] 
    }
}
```

Produces:
[image]

You may have to add the non-breaking space characters (see above) because Graphviz seems to position labels based on the length of the text - longer labels are placed above shorter labels.